# Как добавлять на свою карту JavaScript плагины?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Добрый день,допустим я имею стандартный каркас google Maps javascript API3.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #map { height: 100%; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });
}

</script>
    <script async defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBBZlvm6U0M04HlysCfzG7Ii5Zb4am1wA4&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Допустим я хочу добавить несколько маркеров в разных местах,как мне добавить их,куда вписывать библиотеку,или же сам код маркеров?

Answer (score 0):

В той же документации где вы прочитали про как вставить карту на сайт, есть разделы как работать с апи дальше.
Например [раздел маркеры](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers?hl=ru), который объясняет как вставить их.

```css
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
 var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });
  
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position:  {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });
}
</script>
<script async defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBBZlvm6U0M04HlysCfzG7Ii5Zb4am1wA4&callback=initMap">
</script>
```